# accessing data in many to many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I created many to many association of Teacher and Sclass. ClassTeacher is the join table name.

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :class_teachers
  has_many :Sclasses, :through => :class_teachers

  attr_accessible :teacher_id
  attr_accessible :tname
  attr_accessible :mob
  attr_accessible :email 
end



class Sclass < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_primary_key :year

  has_many :class_teachers
  has_many :teachers, :through => :class_teachers

  attr_accessible :year

end


class ClassTeacher < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :sclass

  attr_accessible :year
  attr_accessible :teacher_id
end
```

I have tlist.html.erb, tnew.html.erb in view -> teachers folder, similarly I have slist.html.erb, snew.html.erb in view -> sclasses folder.

When I add a record for Teacher, it should ask for years too and save the record. Similarly for year it should ask for teacher_ids and save the record. How can I do this?Where will these records be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this answers your question but when you set up a many-to-many relationship your model gets some 'virtual' attributes, called [association_name]_ids. So in your case the Sclass model will have a `teacher_ids` attribute, and the Teacher model will have `sclass_ids`.

So if for example you wanted to assign teachers with ids 1, 2 and 3 to the first sclass you could do this:

```
sclass = Sclass.first
sclass.teacher_ids = [1, 2, 3]
sclass.save
```

To do this in a form you'd probably want something like a row of checkboxes with the name `sclass[teacher_ids][]` (when creating/editing an Sclass), something like this:

```
<% for teacher in Teacher.all -%>
  <%= checkbox_tag "sclass[teacher_ids][]", teacher.id %>
<% end -%>
```